# mutate a column by group and replacing to its 4 median values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, tidyverse, median

I have a dataset:

```
set.seed(1)
data.frame(grouping1 = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 12),
           grouping2 = rep(rep(c("exp1", "exp2", "exp3"), each = 3), times = 4),
           value = runif(36))
```

I would like to replace the values within group A to 4 values center around the median of each grouping1 (in this case is the 5th, 6th, 7th, and 8th values). then repeat these values for each experiment (grouping2). The orders within each exp is irrelevant as I will then take the average for each experiment.

I have two difficulties when trying to do this with tidyverse:

1. I would only want to apply such change to group A only
2. I cannot find a good function to get the 4 median numbers

Maybe customize function is needed.

here is the intended output:

```
set.seed(1)
new_value = runif(36)
new_value[1:12] <- rep(sort(runif(36)[1:12])[5:8],3)
data.frame(grouping1 = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 12),
           grouping2 = rep(rep(c("exp1", "exp2", "exp3"), each = 4), times = 3),
           value = new_value)
```

Comment: I'd like to help, but I'm having some trouble understanding what you'd like to accomplish. Is `new_values` just the median value for each grouping1 i.e. `aggregate(value ~ grouping1, data = dat, FUN = median)`?

Comment: @Skaqqs it is not median only, i would like to have the 5th, 6th, 7th, and 8th values within the grouping1 group A.

Comment: hey @William Wong, were you able to figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using base. I changed the input `df` to have the same number of `grouping2` in each `grouping1` to match your intended output. Let me know if that is an issue. I named the field containing updated values `value2` to make quality control a little easier.

```
set.seed(1)
df<- data.frame(grouping1 = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 12),
           grouping2 = rep(rep(c("exp1", "exp2", "exp3"), each = 4), times = 3),
           value = runif(36))

# We are only interested in Group A
a <- df[df$grouping1 == "A",]
# Calculate difference between median and values
a$diff <- abs(median(a$value) - a$value)
# Values with smallest absolute difference are centered around the median
a <- a[order(a$grouping2),]
a$value2 <- a[a$diff %in% head(sort(a$diff), 4), "value"]
# Join `a` with original dataframe
df$value2 <- NA
rbind(a[,names(df)], df[df$grouping1 != "A",])
```